# How to get the west and east of a BorderLayout attached?

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

This is how a panel with a BorderLayout usually looks :

[image]

I dont want to put anything in the center, so the east and west are separated with a space. How to get them attached? If there isn't a way, what other Layout should I use instead?
Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use something like west and center, and just not use east? It sounds like it would get the layout you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add graphical elements in the desired sections and ignore the others:

```
add(element1, BorderLayout.WEST);
add(element2, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

If you want a space in the center, add it explicitly:

```
add(new JLabel(" "), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can style this several ways without using BorderLayout, which is what I would recommend since BorderLayout is designed with content in the center in mind.

The least complex to present West and East together with no Center is a [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) with 1 row and 2 columns.

If you have a North and South you still want to include, you can then place the GridLayout from above into the 2nd row of a 1 column x 3 row GridLayout.

If you want more complexity and flexibility, you can use a [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), which is akin to a super GridLayout. You can then set a 2 col, 3 row setup, and give North and south 2 columns in their respective rows, and then East and West get a single cell of their own.

Answer (score 1):

Add a panel to the Centre position of your border layout with the grid layout with 2 columns and then add the east and west contents to the panel.

This approach is good if you want both the West and East to take up half the display each in terms of width.

Similar to Compass' answer.